# How to handle values and layout folder for devices having same density but different screen size and resolutions?

Tags: android, user-interface

As I am working on responsive UI for the very first time and having a limited time in hand I am a bit confused with handling UI for different screen sizes and resolution.

For now, I have created 5 values folder(hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi) and added dimens resource file in each folder. Most of the screens looking perfect. 
Consider the case where I have 2 emulators:

1. Screen size: 5.0", Resolution: 1080x1920, densityDpi: 480
2. Screen size: 6.3", Resolution: 1440x2960, densityDpi: 480

As both devices have the same densityDpi, both are using "xxhdpi" folder for the resource files which results in an undesired UI design as shown below:

[image]

I have gone through lots of StackOverflow questions/answers, android docs, and other blogs, but it all seems confusing to me maybe because of time constraints. 
So my question is, how to handle this specific scenario where desityDpi is the same but screen size and resolution are different. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A single layout (or set of layouts) should be able to handle both of those resolutions. We cannot advise you more specifically, since your question does not contain the layout(s) that you are trying. "I have created 5 values folder(hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi) and added dimens resource file in each folder" -- that is a code smell. You should not need different dimension resource values for different densities, as all commonly-used dimension units (`dp`, `sp`) are already density-independent.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your reply. I understand creating different dimens file is not the best way but I have already made a lot of changes and consider the time limit I decided it was the easiest way. If you want my layout file I can post it here.